# How to display all line numbers in Vim?

Tags: line-numbers

In my .vimrc i have added this line

```
set number
```

But it only displays the line number for the lines that exist in the buffer, and not beyond this; after this it just shows `~`.

How can I show line numbers for the entire visual area?

Comment: I don't think you can, and I'm not sure if it would really make any sense. For example if your buffer is thee lines, then doing something like `10G` (to do to the tenth line) simply won't work because from Vim's perspective there isn't a "tenth line"... Vim works a bit different than many other editors in this respect, which could be considered both a good and bad thing depending on your assumptions ;-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker oh ok :) btw thanks for the fast reply. +1

Comment: No line, no line number.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments ! Highly appreciate the fast response ! 

Comment: No line number, no cry. ;)

Comment: I suggest you add 50 lines at the end of your file when you reach it.